# Synonyms for "curate" in US English

Tags: word-choice, verbs, american-english, synonyms

What synonyms are there for "curate", as in (to quote [here](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/curate--2)) to

> select, organize, and present (suitable content, typically for online or computational use), using professional or expert knowledge

I'm from the UK – I just passed a sentence under the eyes of a US friend who said it didn't sound quite right. The best alternative we could come up with was "pick and choose".

I'm wording a press statement, so I'd like something succinct. The contexts are

> Blah today introduced Blah, a revolutionary experience on the Apple® iPad that curates the best ... for the user.
>
> Blah learns what you like, and curates streams of it for you

Comment: How about *selects* or *creates* depending on what it actually does.

Comment: Would 'aggregate' suit?

Comment: *Curate* is the correct term here. You do not need another one.  It just sounds academic is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using variously "select", "showcase" and "compile".

Answer (score 2):

**[com·pile](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/compile)** (the free dictionary)
*tr.v.* **com·piled, com·pil·ing, com·piles**

**2**. To put together or compose from materials gathered from several sources: *compile an encyclopedia*.

In a context where the material is not necessarily of a cultural or similar nature, *compile* can be used. However, note that unlike *curate*, *compile* does not include the sense of either *to look after* or *to present*.

Answer (score 1):

One word I've heard used is **cull**.  Here are a few dictionary entries:

> **cull** to collect something such as information from different places : *recipes culled from magazines* <sup>1</sup>
>
> **cull** to choose or gather the best or required examples <sup>2</sup>
>
> **cull** 1. To pick out from others; select. 2. To gather; collect. <sup>3</sup>
>
> **cull** select from a large quantity; obtain from a variety of sources :
> *anecdotes culled from Greek and Roman history* <sup>4</sup>

The word *cull* also implies, by picking out the best, you are also discarding the least desirable.  (In fact, by *culling a herd*, you selectively slaughter the inferior animals; most [dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/cull) also make reference to this other usage of the word).  Yet there is plenty of precendent for applying the word to *data*, as evidenced by [this Google book listing](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22cull%20data%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en).

<sub>R E F E R E N C E S</sub>

<sup>1</sup> from [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/cull#cull_4)
<sup>2</sup> from [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cull)
<sup>3</sup> from American Heritage, copied from [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/cull)
<sup>4</sup> from [Oxford](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cull?view=uk)

Comment: More commonly though, the verb is used in the phrase *culled from*, so it directs the focus to the source than to itself or to what is actually culled or culled into.

Comment: @Kris: most commonly, perhaps, but certainly not [exclusively](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22cull%20the%20data%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1970,cd_max:2005&lr=lang_en).

Comment: Three of the results on page-1 contain the *cull from* phrases. Rest of the seven use *cull* in the express sense of *reduce* / *extract* / *filter*, *not collect* / *gather*. We can draw the conclusions accordingly.

Comment: @Kris: What you said describes why I like the word _cull_. O.P. wants a word to connote "pick and choose" - presumably, trimming down from a wealth of content, ultimately selecting the ones the user will "like." That sounds like culling to me (or maybe I misread the O.P.'s *blahs* and ellipses).

Answer (score 0):

Here in the U.S., I have heard the word "curate" in this sense used exclusively of art shows - "A retrospective of the paintings of Ed Ruscha, curated by So-and-so."